# Python: split in chunks and reform the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

| fund code | date | NAV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-04 | 1.0000 |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-05 | 1.0001 |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-06 | 1.0023 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-08 | 1.0000 |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-09 | 0.9998 |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-10 | 1.0001 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-04 | 2.0021 |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-05 | 2.0044 |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-06 | 2.0305 |

I want to reform it into this:

| Date | fund 1 | fund 2 | fund 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-08 | NAV | NAV | NAV |
| 2020-02-09 | NAV | NAV | NAV |
| 2020-02-10 | NAV | NAV | NAV |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-05-04 | NAV | NAV | NAV |
| 2022-05-05 | NAV | NAV | NAV |
| 2022-05-06 | NAV | NAV | NAV |

I formed a new dataframe with the fund codes as column names and the date as index. How to move the elements from the old table into the new one?

```py
date=set(df['date'])
cd=set(df['fund code'])
days=pd.date_range(min(date),max(date),freq='D')
Newdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=cd,index=days)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.pivot`:

```py
df.pivot(index="date", columns="fund code", values="NAV").fillna(0)
```

This outputs:

```py
fund code   fund 1     fund 2     fund 3
date
2020-02-08           0  1.0000             0
2020-02-09           0  0.9998             0
2020-02-10           0  1.0001             0
2021-01-04   1.0000             0          0
2021-01-05   1.0001             0          0
2021-01-06   1.0023             0          0
2022-05-04           0          0  2.0021
2022-05-05           0          0  2.0044
2022-05-06           0          0  2.0305
```